# How can I control the Romances in Mass Effect 2?

Tags: mass-effect-2

In Mass Effect I tried to get as far as I could in dialogues with characters, even though I was trying to remain neutral as to not get involved with anyone so I could remain loyal to Tali in Mass Effect 2, despite my best efforts to remain neutral but view as much dialogue Ashley came up but I had to blow her off.

Now playing Mass Effect 2 and I'm beginning to worry that my interactions with Kelly may be setting on the path to romance her while when I get Jack I want to be friendly with her however my target is Tali.

I am wondering, in Mass Effect 2 is there a way to control the relationships without having to just flat out ignore characters (so I still get the chance to explore their dialogue), like a particular conversation response that'll lock me with them or something? I'm on the Paragon path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Mass Effect 2 Wikia [Romance page](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Romance):

> For a male Shepard, a love interest is "locked in" once you express
> interest at the following dialogue points:
>
> - Jack: "I want to talk about us." At the point where she says "I'm not    interested in some dumbshit love affair. It never goes right."
>   To    prevent locking-in, say "Never mind".
> - Tali: "I want to talk about you." At the point where she beckons you    toward the drive core and says "I've been thinking about the
>   last    time we talked." To prevent locking-in, say "So you're not
>   interested?" followed by "I need to think about this."
> - Miranda: "Can we talk?" At the point where she says "I don't know    what this is, if it's just stress, or blowing off steam, or..." you
>   cannot opt out; every option results in either becoming locked-in, or
>   the relationship being broken off permanently. It is recommended that
>   the player save before talking to Miranda.
>
> At this point you know that Shepard has successfully 'locked in' that
> romance. Shepard can still express an interest in other crew members.
> However, the new love interest will 'challenge' Shepard's
> love-triangle and force Shepard to dump the 'locked-in' option in
> order to be with them.

I've only tried to romance Miranda (and apparently after trying that I was locked-in no matter what), but I did also get the Jack dialog.

For more information (about Kelly and Samara/Morinth), you should check out the romance page for yourself. There's a bit about loyalties on there as well.